# Opensuse Php Version 5.3 to 5.6

Tags: opensuse, php-5.6

On my machine currently PHP5.3 version available now I need to update it PHP 5.6. The available operating system is Opensue.

If someone have an idea please reply.

Comment: **Update - Opensuse 42.3** The URL is at http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/devel:/languages:/php:/php56/openSUSE_Leap_42.3/

Answer (score 0):

For openSUSE Leap 42.2 run the following as root:

```
zypper addrepo http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/devel:languages:php/openSUSE_Leap_42.2/devel:languages:php.repo
zypper refresh
zypper remove php5
zypper install php5
```

For openSUSE Leap 42.1 run the following as root:

```
zypper addrepo http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/devel:languages:php/openSUSE_Leap_42.1/devel:languages:php.repo
zypper refresh
zypper remove php5
zypper install php5
```

For openSUSE 13.2 run the following as root:

```
zypper addrepo http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/devel:languages:php/openSUSE_13.2/devel:languages:php.repo
zypper refresh
zypper remove php5
zypper install php5
```

Answer (score 0):

**openSUSE Leap 42.2**

There is no 5.6 version on suggested repos (Jan 2018), so you have to use another one:

```
zypper ar -f -c http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/devel:/languages:/php:/php56/openSUSE_Leap_42.2/ PHP56
zypper dup --from PHP56
```

Answer (score 0):

I had installed it using this:
sudo zypper install http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/devel:/languages:/php:/php56/SLE_12_SP3/x86_64/php5-5.6.40-5.1.x86_64.rpm